# using Threads to check the clipboard each second

Tags: java, multithreading, clipboard

```
public class Checker implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String s = "hello everyone this is the clipboard program";
        ClipBoard clipBoard = new ClipBoard();
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            result= clipBoard.changeTheText(result);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("String from Clipboard:" + result);
    }

}
```

I know it may be just a simple use of Threads but I'm not sure how it works.
I want ta check the clipboard each second with a Thread and see if it has changed by the user or not. Right now I can just print my clipboard for once

Comment: Use scheduled executor service.

Comment: Do you want to know how threads work in general? Or are you asking how to use the Java `Thread` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Checker` class is a `Runnable`, so you can run it in a `Thread` by doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Checker checker = new Checker();
    Thread thread = new Thread(checker);
    thread.start();
}
```

However, this will execute your `run()` method just once. If you want to execute it periodically, you should rewrite it following a structure like this one:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            // ... your code here
            Thread.sleep(1000); // this will pause the thread for 1 second
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Now your code is inside an infinite loop and it will be executed every second. If you want to stop it, just call `thread.interrupt()`.

Answer (score 3):

A [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) should do the trick here

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Checker(), 1, 1, SECONDS);
```

This will run your `Checker` after a 1 second delay, and every second after that.